# Using P5js with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I want to **use p5js** **with reactjs** but *how* can **render** a **canvas** in the app component?
can I copy this into the index.html file?

```
<meta name="viewport" width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0>
    <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
<script src="../p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/using-react-with-p5-js/5565/2

Comment: nothing i think i can't do it

Comment: Please try to be more specific. Are you getting an error message? What's happening when you run this code? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your canvas in **setup()** (executed once by p5.js) and render (draw on) your canvas in **draw()** (p5.js executes this function at default 60fps)

**html:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../p5.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scetch.js"></script>
```

**sketch.js:**

```
function setup() 
{
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() // main loop
{
    background(0);
    circle(50, 50, 25);       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can copy that into the index.js file, just make sure that all the p5js library code is in the public folder, and put this

```
<script src="../p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
```

into index.html